# definite integral of a complex function

Tags: integration

I wonder if there is a way to evaluate this definite integral...
$$\frac{2}{\pi}(\ln (2) + \int_{0}^{\infty}({\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^{4}} - \frac{4e^{-4t}}{(1 - e^{-4t})^{2}}}} - \frac{1}{t^2 + 1})dt)$$

... can you suggest a website or online calculator that I can use?

Comment: This is being integrated with respect to x or with respect to t? Also, integrals are linear operators, and you're integrating a sum of three things. If the integral of each one converges, you can separate the integral. But the integral of the first part alone does not converge (goes to infinity), so you would need one of the other parts to go to minus infinity in order for that integral to converge.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic sorry wrong entry of variables...I edit it to the correct one tnx!

Comment: What is that 2 in the squareroot

Comment: @grdgfgr sorry...I'll correct that

Comment: still diverges_

Comment: This is hilarious. The original post still has unmatched parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use series expansion of (a+b)^(1/2) to convert the square root into integral powers ,use integration by parts on each term of expansion as both terms independently can be easily integrated by substitution. cant show the calculations as i dont kno how to use symbols

first clearly specify domain

Comment: tnx a lot!!!! little bit tedious yet worth of a try tnx!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{ \frac {1} {t^{4}} - \frac {4e^{-4t}}{(1-4e^{-4t})^2}}$$

Diverges at zero. Which is (probably) one of many problems with that integral.